# function not returning days of the week

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

Instead of typing in an array containing the days of the week I created a function to do it for me. However, when I console log I'm getting an array with complete different values. Please tell me where my code needs tweaking to get the output I expect.

```js
const dayNames = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (item, i) => {
  return new Date(0, i).toLocaleString("en-US", { days: "long" });
});

console.log(dayNames);
```

Comment: So you are making dates for 1900? And you are setting the month, not days of the week `new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]])`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

Answer (score 1):

It's `"weekday"` not `"days"`.

Additionally, as other's have mentioned, you are not setting the day of the month correctly. The [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) requires you to pass in the `year`, followed by the `monthIndex` and then the `day`. Make sure you add another `0` before the `i` parameter that you are passing into the constructor.

```js
console.logJSON = msg => console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));

/**
 * Returns an array containing the days of the week.
 * @param {String} locales - specify the language
 * @param {Number} startDayOfWeek - day of week offset
 * @return {String[]} an array containing days of the week.
 */
const daysOfWeek = (locales = 'en-US', startDayOfWeek = 0) =>
  Array.from({ length: 7 }, (x, i) =>
    new Date(0, 0, i + startDayOfWeek)
      .toLocaleString(locales, { weekday: 'long' }));

// ============= Usage =============
console.logJSON(daysOfWeek());        // US English (default)
console.logJSON(daysOfWeek('es', 1)); // Español
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Worth noting that this works because a year of 0 is treated as 1900, and in the first iteration when *i* is 0, `new Date(1900,0,0)` produces a date for 31 Dec 1899, which happens to be a Sunday. So yes it "works", but perhaps by accident more than design. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `days` to `weekday`
2. add one more zero to the date initialization (year, month, date) currently you change date instead month

```js
const dayNames = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (item, i) => {
  return new Date(0, 0, i).toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: "long" });
});

console.log(dayNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were incrementing the months instead of the days.

The days are int the third parameter of the Date constructor.

Furthermore, the option you are looking for is `weekdays`, not `days`

```js
const dayNames = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (item, i) => {
  return new Date(0,0,i).toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: 'long' })
});

console.log(dayNames); //["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```